# There are 2 Reacts in one project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am currently developing a React Web App and I suddenly started to get `invalid hook call` error. After a little research I found out that I have two copies of `React`. Even each css file has one more of the same

[image: css]

However after I tried almost every way, there is also a github issue opened about it [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) and it didn't help me either. Please help me I really get started to run out of solutions

**my webpack.config.js if needed**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const port = 8080
const host = "127.0.0.1"

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
/*     libraryTarget: 'commonjs' */
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            /* name: "public/images/[name].[ext]" */ //Gives Error??
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve : { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"], /* alias:{react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'), 'react-dom':path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom')} */},
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    port: port,
    host: host,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
    })
  ],
  /* externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  } */
};
```

Comment: Try clearing the data in your browser and try rebuilding again.

Answer (score 1):

These are few things you can try. We had faced similar issue.

- make sure your react and react-dom at same version
- if no, have them at same version
- else, add an alias in your webpack (the way you have done but commented), add it only for react.

```js
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            react: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if your webpack config is at the same level as your node_modules, above will work. Otherwise update the react path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was `HtmlWebpackPlugin` extension, somehow it created a child app component and rendered the same things again. I really don't know how that happened but after deleting this extension everything turned back to normal.